# Selectively allowing classes to use others' private class methods, or equivalent solution

Tags: ruby, class-method, private-methods

In my project `Bar`, I have this class `Foo`, whose instances represent unique, named real-world objects. References to these instances are scattered under good care around the data structures in my project, but also, I have decided to make them accessible by their names. For this purpose, class Foo itself traces its instances, like

```
module Bar
  class Foo
    attr_reader :name

    def initialize( name )
      @name = name
    end

    def self.new *args, &block
      new_instance = super
      n_i_name = new_instance.name
      ( @instances ||= {} ).merge! new_instance => n_i_name
      return new_instance
    end

    def inspect; "Foo instance #{name}" end
  end
end
```

Now this is a common pattern. Typically, to access the instances, one can establish a public class method in `Foo`:

```
class << Bar::Foo
  def instance( i )
    case i
    when self then i
    else @instances.rassoc( i ).first end
  end
end

i = Bar::Foo.new "John Smith"
#=> Foo instance John Smith
i.object_id
#=> 68997470
Bar::Foo.instance( "John Smith" ).object_id
#=> 68997470
```

But the problem is, that there are analogical classes with named instances under `Bar` module, such as `Bar::Baz`, `Bar::Quux` and so on, which need to access `Foo` instances and each other by name. So I figured that keeping order in the way these various classes access each others instances by name is the responsibility of `Bar` module itself, and I created public module methods in it:

```
module Bar
  # Foo method blah blah blah...
  def self.Foo( i ); Foo.instance i end

  # Baz method blah blah blah...
  def self.Baz( i ); Baz.instance i end

  # Quux method blah blah blah...
  def self.Quux( i ); Quux.instance i end
end
```

Whenever classes `Foo`, `Baz`, `Quux` refer to each other, they use `Bar.Foo( "John Smith" )` style calls, which makes possible referring to these instances also by their unique names. Now my problem is, that this still doesn't seem 100% kosher to me. When I run `rdoc` to create documentation for `Bar` module, public class methods `#Foo`, `#Baz`, `#Quux` make it to the documentation. But these are not really intended to be a part of the user interface. So I have the following options, each of which has a problem:

1. Include `#Foo`, `#Baz`, `#Quux` in the user interface. **Problem**: The user does not really need them that badly; it was not my design intention to have them in UI.
2. Add `# :nodoc:` directive to them to prevent `rdoc` from documenting them. **Problem**: It does not feel right. It is not like `Bar.Foo` and friends were excluded from the user interface. It feels more like they are still part of the UI, but undocumented, secret. I don't want that.
3. Declare them private using `#private_class_method`. But then, even if the instances `#Foo`, `#Baz`, `#Quux` access each other by name during normal operation, they, too, have to use `Bar.send :Foo, "John Smith"` style.

The question: The option 3. seems least harmful. But still, it is not perfect. Ideally, I would like to have methods `Bar.Foo`, `Bar.Baz`, `Bar.Quux` protected in such way, that these guys can call each other by names by simply calling `Bar.Foo "John Smith"`, while the user has to use `Bar.send :Foo, "John Smith"`, and these module methods are not documented for the user. What other options, if any, do I have to achieve this state of affairs? Is there a way to selectively allow some classes to use somebody else's private methods at will? Also, I have no experience with protected class methods, could that be a solution? Thanks for your time spent reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Understanding private methods in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293215/understanding-private-methods-in-ruby) and search SO for private/protected, there are lots of material to read.

Protected class method :

```
class Foo
    class << self
        def prot
            puts "self.prot"
        end
        protected :prot
    end
...

Bar::Foo.prot #=> protected method `prot' called for Bar::Foo:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Nice answer, but of a sligthly different question. Btw. is there such thing as protected class methods?

Comment: It seems more difficult to realize : see above (not enough editing capability here).

Comment: Can you give an example of "classes Foo, Baz, Quux refer to each other". Why have all three a different access method to get instance ? Why not factor out all the instance/naming mechanism in a superclass ?

Comment: This is actually, as you might have figuered, a real-world problem I'm facing in my project. Finally, I did exactly what you suggest: I factored out the naming/instance listing into a mixin employing decorator pattern. More precisely, I adapted my older mixin performing fake constant magic for classes other than Class and Struct to also take care of this. I have more or less solved this problem, and I give you credit for trying to help. I'm not really fond of answering own questions on SO, do you think I should do it?

Comment: In cases where nobody answers, and the OP eventually find a solution, there is a good reason to post it. As I have spent some time reading your question and trying to understand what you wanted to do,  I'm interested to see your solution :)