# Global methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

If all 'functions' in Ruby are methods, so when I call methods without explicitly mentioning the object they are invoked on, who are they sent to?

The Ruby Programming Language book (Flanagan & Matsumoto) says if the object is omitted the method is invoked on self.

So if this code works

```
p "123"
```

Then this should work

```
self.p "123"
```

but it doesnt!

In this case I ran this in global scope so self is main and self.class is Object. So I can't invoke p on a simple Object instance (which makes sense).

I understand that Object includes Kernel where p is declared.  How does the interpreter know how to access this declaration?

Comment: The method is private. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293215/understanding-private-methods-in-ruby

Comment: Did you actually read the error message? It explains quite clearly what is going on.

Comment: It's hard to guess from NoMethodError that it is the same object being invoked and that the method is private.  Also Ruby's approach to private methods is not trivial for a Ruby beginner, especially after experience with Java, C++ etc

Comment: Oh sorry you are right, it does actually say private method called. I am using Netbeans and yes I didn't even read the whole line. Stupid :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For runtime Ruby has special object the `main`.

It's some kind of trick that all code runs in the context of this object.

So when you're typing methods like `puts`, `p` and so on, all of them are calling in the context of `self` object and passing to `self` object.

And here's the second thing - the access control.
As you probably know, Ruby has keywords like `private`, `protected` and `public` - all of them manage the access of calling methods on object. Ruby is checking this access control only when you're have construction like

`<name_of_object>.your_method` and `self.your_method`

So when you're typing

```
self.p "something"
```

Ruby will decline this call because the `p` method is private method.

Comment: Thank you, your answer led me to fully understanding this issue.  I posted an explicit example

Answer (score 0):

It is simply an access issue as the user megas explained.  This example shows it explicitly-

```
class Object

  def checking
    p self
  end

  private

  def private_checking
    p self
  end

end


checking                  #=>main
self.checking             #=>main

private_checking          #=>main
self.private_checking     #=>NoMethodError
```