# calling module method into another module in Ruby

Tags: ruby

FIle module.rb

```
module CardExpiry
  def check_expiry value
    return true
  end
end
```

file include.rb

```
#raise File.dirname(__FILE__).inspect
require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/module.rb"

 module Include
     include CardExpiry
  def self.function 
    raise (check_expiry 1203).inspect
  end
end
```

calling

```
Include::function
```

is this possible ?

Error trigger when calling :

```
`function': undefined method `check_expiry' for Include:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is this possible?"? Have you tried it? That would be the obvious way to check. The answer is probably "yes", but I don't understand why you haven't tried it.

Comment: i tried .. but no success yet

Comment: I apologise for my above comment - I see that you were actually having an error; please in future include any error messages that you see, thanks.

Comment: @KenY-N i edited question .. now you can see error message at bottom of question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You stumbled over the [difference of `include` and `extend`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156362/what-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-ruby).

- `include` makes the method in the included module available to *instances* of your class
- `extend` makes the methods in the included module available in the *class*

When defining a method with `self.method_name` and you access `self` within that method, `self` is bound to the current class.

`check_expiry`, however, is included and thus only available on the instance side.

To fix the problem either `extend CardExpiry`, or make `check_expiry` a class method.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your problem in a bit more detail, and the issue is your `module.rb` file:

```
module CardExpiry
  def self.check_expiry value
    return true
  end
end
```

First, there was an `end` missing from the file - both `def` and `module` need to be closed.

Second, the magical `self.` in the `def` line turns the method into a pseudo-global function - [this answer explains it better than I can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15485132/1270789).

Furthermore, to call the method, you need to use:

```
raise (CardExpiry::check_expiry 1203).inspect
```