# Calling selected methods of a module from another module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have defined a method in module A. I want to call the same method from the moduleB

```
module A
  included do
    def self.some_func
    end
  end
end

module B
  some_func # It raise error (NoMethodError: undefined method). How solve this?
end

module C
  include A
  include B
end
```

This doesn't work. Is it possible to call a function that is defined by one module in another module?

Comment: Did you try `extend A` in module B ? check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973906/calling-module-method-into-another-module-in-ruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `module A` should be raising an `ArgumentError` unless it also has an `extends ActiveSupport::Concern` at the top. Without `ActiveSupport::Concern`, you'd be calling the [`Module#included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-included) instance method here:

```
included do
  ...
end
```

but that requires an argument.

If you say this:

```
module A
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    def self.some_func
    end
  end
end
```

then you'll get the [`included`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-included) you're trying to use and the `module A` that you're expecting.

Also, `module B` doesn't `include A` so it has nowhere to get `some_func` from so this:

```
module B
  some_func
end
```

will give you a `NoMethodError`. If you include `A`:

```
module B
  include A
  some_func
end
```

then it will work.