# Why can I call private methods via Object#send, but not directly call said methods?

Tags: ruby

Why can I call a private method via `Object#send(:private_method)`?

What is the purpose of Ruby's `private` keyword if not to prevent direct calling of certain methods?

Is there anyway to reliably prevent objects from being able to call certain methods?

```
class Person
  def say_hi
    "hi"
  end

  private
  def private_say_hi
    "private hi"
  end
end

me = Person.new
me.say_hi
#=> "hi"

me.private_say_hi
#Error: private method `private_say_hi' called for #<Person:0x00558df4b79a08>

me.send(:private_say_hi)
#=> "private hi"
```

Comment: When designing an interface, a private method can be used to indicate that the method is unstable and should not be used directly by an object.

Comment: It's doesn't maintain full use of the send method, and sets off a warning message, but here is an example of overriding the send method to prevent access to a private method: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639857/how-to-disable-a-certain-method-in-ruby-from-being-called-in-the-console)

Comment: You will need to override a lot of things... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349624/how-to-call-methods-dynamically-based-on-their-name/26284769#26284769 You may be able to do a cheap check regarding the caller...

Comment: FWIW, you might have better luck with "Is there anyway to reliably prevent objects from being able to call certain methods?" as the title of the question, and edit your question to comply with the theme. Of course, then it is probably just a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639857/how-to-disable-a-certain-method-in-ruby-from-being-called-in-the-console. As it is right now, it is broad and opinion based...

Comment: Better that they can be called, anyway, otherwise the stymied programmer will simply copy/paste the code into the new location. Then you would have two problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Why can I call a private method via Object#send(:private_method)?

Look carefully at what you did:

```
me.send(:private_say_hi)
```

In nowhere the method `private_say_hi` is called in the form:

```
me.private_say_hi
```

That is why. Isn't is obvious?

- What is the purpose of Ruby's private keyword if not to prevent direct calling of certain methods?

Just as the definition says. To avoid being called with an explicit receiver.

- Is there anyway to reliably prevent objects from being able to call certain methods?

Use `undef`, `undef_method`, or `remove_method` depending on you needs.