# Ruby: calling private methods from inside with self keyword

Tags: ruby, self, private-members

```
class MyClass
  def test
    puts my_id
    puts self.my_id
  end

  private

  def my_id
    115
  end
end

m = MyClass.new
m.test
```

This script results in an output:

```
115
priv.rb:4:in `test': private method `my_id' called for #<MyClass:0x2a50b68> (NoMethodError)
    from priv.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

What is the difference between calling methods from inside with `self` keyword and without it?

From my Delphi and C# experience: there was no difference, and `self` could be used to avoid name conflict with local variable, to denote that I want to call an instance function or refer to instance variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding private methods in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293215/understanding-private-methods-in-ruby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ruby a `private` method is simply one that cannot be called with an explicit receiver, i.e with anything to the left of the `.`, no exception is made for `self`, except in the case of setter methods (methods whose name ends in `=`)

To disambiguate a non setter method call you can also use parens, ie

```
my_id()
```

For a private setter method, i.e if you had

```
def my_id=(val)
end
```

then you can't make ruby parse this as a method call by adding parens. You have to use `self.my_id=` for ruby to parse this as a method call - this is the exception to "you can't call setter methods with an explicit receiver"

Comment: There is one exception: you can call private setters with an explicit `self`

Comment: So you can - hadn't thought to try that out!

Comment: @Stefan, I think "can" should be "must", for the same reason that a public setter must be called with `self`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland is right. It should rather be: you *cannot* call a private setter *without* `self`, because otherwise it would be interpreted as assigning a local variable.

Comment: That was rather  poorly worded on my behalf - after Stefan pointed that our I was clumsily trying to say that you can't use parens in this case - presumably that is the motivation for the deviation from the general definition of private.