# Definition of method in top level

Tags: ruby

I'm wondering about definition of method in top level.

```
puts RUBY_VERSION #=> 2.1.5
def greet
  "hello, world"
end
class Object
    greet #=> "hello, world"
end
```

Why does `greet` act like private class method?

```
puts RUBY_VERSION #=> 2.1.5
def greet
  "good morning"
end

# case 1
Object.private_methods(false).grep /greet/ #=> []
# case 2
Object.private_instance_methods(false).grep /greet/ #=> [:greet]
# case 3
Object.private_methods(true).grep /greet/ #=> [:greet]
```

In case 3, I found that `greet` is a private class method. But I'm wondering which class owns `greet` as a private class method. `Object` inherits itself?

## Edit

I update my question.

### Question #1

Does definition of method mean adding some methods in `Object` as private instance method.
Is this correct ?

### Question #2

`Object` is an instance of `Class`. So, `Object` owns private class methods. These methods as private instance methods in `Class`.
Is this correct ?

### Question #3

depends on question #1 and #2. `Class` inherits `Object`. So, `Class` owns `greet` as private class method and private instance method.
Is this correct ?

Comment: "Why does greet act like private class method?" Not clear what you mean by that.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does `greet` act like private class method?

It doesn't. It acts like a private instance method. (In fact, there are no class methods in Ruby, only instance methods. The question is not whether a method is an instance method or a class method, rather it's what class the instance method is defined in.)

Methods defined at the top-level become private instance methods of `Object`.

> ```
> # case 1
> Object.private_methods(false).grep /greet/ #=> []
> # case 2
> Object.private_instance_methods(false).grep /greet/ #=> [:greet]
> # case 3
> Object.private_methods(true).grep /greet/ #=> [:greet]
> ```
>
> In case 3, I found that `greet` is a private class method.

Like I said above: there are no class methods in Ruby.

`greet` is a private instance method of `Object`. `Object` is an instance of `Class`, `Class` is a subclass of `Module`, `Module` is a subclass of `Object`, ergo `Object` is an instance of `Object` i.e. itself.

Put another way: methods defined in `Object` are available for all objects. Classes are objects, too, ergo methods defined in `Object` are available for all classes, including `Object`.

> But I'm wondering which class owns `greet` as a private class method.

None. There are no class methods in Ruby. `greet` is a private instance method of `Object`.

> `Object` inherits itself?

No. `Object` is an *instance of* itself.

> ### Question #1
>
> Does definition of method mean adding some methods in `Object` as private instance method.
>   Is this correct ?

Methods defined at the top-level become private instance methods of `Object`.

> ### Question #2
>
> `Object` is an instance of `Class`. So, `Object` owns private class methods. These methods as private instance methods in `Class`.
>   Is this correct ?

I cannot parse your question, sorry.

However, there are no private instance methods of `Class` in your examples. The only method in your example is `greet`, which is a private instance method of `Object`, not `Class`.

If you want to know who owns a method, you can just ask Ruby:

```
method(:greet).owner
# => Object
```

> ### Question #3
>
> depends on question #1 and #2. `Class` inherits `Object`. So, `Class` owns >`greet` as private class method and private instance method.
>   Is this correct ?

No. There are no class methods in Ruby, only instance methods. And `greet` is not owned by `Class`, it is a private instance method of `Object`:

```
method(:greet).owner
# => Object
```

Answer (score 1):

Using irb, defining `greet` at the top-level does NOT define `greet` as a private method, at least using ruby 2.x:

```
$ irb
> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.3.0"
> def greet; "hi"; end
=> :greet

> Object.methods.grep /greet/
=> [:greet]

> Object.private_methods.grep /greet/
=> []
> Object.private_instance_methods.grep /greet/
=> []
```

In ruby, a "private method" is one that cannot be called with an explicit "receiver" in the usual way. (See e.g. [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293215/understanding-private-methods-in-ruby).)  Since `self.greet` and `Object.greet` both produce the same result as `greet`, it follows that `greet` (defined at the top-level in irb) cannot be a private method.

The situation is different when using the ruby compiler.

Comment: oops! I tried with ruby 2.1.5. But i tried again with ruby 2.4.0. I found same results

Comment: That's a well-known, age-old bug in IRb. Do not rely on IRb for inferences about the behavior of Ruby.

Comment: The IRB binds methods in the top level scope to `main` as public methods for convenience (and that's weird). If you run your code above as a script with `ruby YOUR_FILE_NAME` then `greet` will be a `private` method