# Can someone help explain the post_initialize callback for class creation (Sandi Metz)

Tags: ruby

I am reading Sandi Metz's POODR and have come across a coding principle that I don't quite understand. Here is the code:

```
class Bicycle
 attr_reader :size, :chain, :tire_size

  def initialize(args = {})
    @size = args[:size] || 1
    @chain = args[:chain] || 2
    @tire_size = args[:tire_size] || 3
    post_initialize(args)
  end
end

class MountainBike < Bicycle
  attr_reader :front_shock, :rear_shock

  def post_initialize(args)
    @front_shock = args[:front_shock]
    @rear_shock = args[:rear_shock]
  end
end

mb = MountainBike.new(front_shock: 4, rear_shock: 5)
puts mb.size
puts mb.chain
puts mb.tire_size
puts mb.front_shock
puts mb.rear_shock
```

This code will output `1,2,3,4,5` for its respective attributes. What I don't understand is the method look up.

When a mountain bike is instantiated, because it does not have its own `initialize` method, it will travel up the method lookup chain onto its super class (`Bicycle`). But now from there, it seems that Bicycle then moves back down into MountainBike's post_initialize method. Instead of continuing up the method chain, how can it go back down? Is `post_initialize` a ruby keyword like `initialize` in that it serves some sort of special function? Is there some other ruby introspection methods I can use to see what is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important thing to understand here is that in this code:

```
def initialize(args = {})
  # ...
  post_initialize(args)
end
```

...`post_initialize` has an implicit receiver, `self`. In other words, `post_initialize(args)` here is equivalent<sup>†</sup> to `self.post_initialize(args)`, and `self` is an instance of MountainBike.  Method lookup always starts with the receiver's class,<sup>‡</sup> so it has no trouble finding `MountainBike#post_initialize`.

<sup>†</sup> That's a lie; it's not equivalent when it comes to privacy; `private` methods [cannot be called with an explicit receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293215/understanding-private-methods-in-ruby).
<sup>‡</sup> That's also a lie; it actually starts with the receiver's singleton class, but then it tries its class.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about the `post_initialize` method.  It is merely a plain vanilla instance method of the subclass.

In Ruby, a superclass instance method is able to call a subclass instance method, even in its constructor. Check out this irb session:

```
2.3.0 :003 > class Base
2.3.0 :004?>   def initialize
2.3.0 :005?>     foo
2.3.0 :006?>     end
2.3.0 :007?>   end
 => :initialize
2.3.0 :015 > class Derived < Base
2.3.0 :016?>   def foo
2.3.0 :017?>     puts 'I am foo.'
2.3.0 :018?>     end
2.3.0 :019?>   end
 => :foo
2.3.0 :020 > Derived.new
I am foo.
```

The usual way this is done is by having the subclass call `super`, but I guess Sandi is suggesting the `post_initialize` approach to require that the subclass provide its own initialization, or formally decline to do so by implementing an empty method. (Plus, writers of subclasses may forget to call `super`.)  Here is how it would be done with super:

```
2.3.0 :001 > class Base
2.3.0 :002?>   def initialize
2.3.0 :003?>     puts 'in base'
2.3.0 :004?>     end
2.3.0 :005?>   end
 => :initialize
 => #<Derived:0x007fda6ba291d8>
2.3.0 :012 > class Derived < Base
2.3.0 :013?>   def initialize
2.3.0 :014?>     super
2.3.0 :015?>     puts 'in derived'
2.3.0 :016?>     end
2.3.0 :017?>   end
 => :initialize
2.3.0 :018 > Derived.new
in base
in derived
 => #<Derived:0x007fda6b104b98>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Keith. I'd just like to add to make it explicitly clear - "self" is the implicit receiver, and given the instance was a derived class, than self would be the derived class instance, which could then access the relevant method which would exist in that particular derived class (as per Jordan's answer).